# multiplot of isolines and points creates two axis frames

Tags: gnuplot

I've created a multiplot containing an isoline plot f(x,y) and a point, (0,0) on the zero level set of the isoline plot. Unfortunately the point plot appears to create a second axis frames as shown below

```
f(x,y)=2*x**2 - x + 2*y**2 - y - 2
set multiplot
set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [-3:3]
set isosamples 250
set contour
unset surface
set view map
set key out
set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
splot f(x,y)
plot "< echo '1 1'"
set nomultiplot
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

**Update**

A bit more context. In the larger problem I am using multiplot to superimpose two isoline plots, as hinted below. Both isoline plots share a common axis frame.

```
...
set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
splot f(x,y)
set cntrparam levels discrete 0
g(x,y)=(x - 1)**2 + y**2 - 1
splot g(x,y)
```

[image: isoline plot and single point]

Comment: What is your function g(x,y)? What do you want as legend? Labels for both contours  f(x,y) and g(x,y) and the single point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are additional requirements that mandate use of multiplot, the simplest solution is to draw your single point as a label instead. The label comes with a point for free. You only want the point, so the label text is an empty string.

If this was a proxy question for a more complicated requirement, please edit the question to give more detail.

```
f(x,y)=2*x**2 - x + 2*y**2 - y - 2

set label 1 "" at 1,1,0 point pt 7 lc "blue"

set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [-3:3]
set isosamples 250
set contour
unset surface
set view map
set key out
set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
splot f(x,y) with lines
```

[image]

**Edit**
The multiplot version:

```
f(x,y)=2*x**2 - x + 2*y**2 - y - 2
g(x,y)=(x - 1)**2 + y**2 - 1

set label 1 "" at 1,1,0 point pt 7 lc "blue"

set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [-3:3]
set isosamples 250
set contour
unset surface
set view map

set multiplot

set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
set key out top
splot f(x,y) with lines

set cntrparam levels discrete  0
set key out bottom
splot g(x,y) with lines

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is indeed a part of a larger problem. Therefore I have added some context to my question.

Comment: OK, but two splot commands with the same xrange and yrange should superimpose nicely.  Do they not?

Comment: @Ethan they would superimpose nicely only if you set fixed margins

Comment: Yes they do. I was just giving additional context. I have added the formula for g(x,y)

Comment: Good.  Then you just need to add `set key outside bottom` before the second plot and the two legends will stack properly on the right side.

Comment: just to mention: the graphs superimpose because the legend has (by accident) the same width. It would not align if your second function would be `g123456(x,y)`. To be sure that they align, you would have to fix the margins.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my suggestion:

- you don't need multiplot (I would use it only if absolute necessary)
- plot the contour data into a table and instead of 3D splot and "set view map" use a 2D plot. Because after `set contour` you cannot plot a single datapoint as non-grid data.
- there are [a lot of ways to *plot* a single data point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZqZ8.png). My preference would be without system call.
- you might want to `set size ratio -1`, then a circle appears as a circle

**Update:**

Here is the extended example after you mentioned your second contour function `g(x,y)`.

Just to mention the differences between a multiplot solution and a single plot solution:

**Script (multiplot):** (with fixed margins and legend box positions relative to screen)

- easy handling of the legend entries and boxes (but manual positioning if more than 2)
- you need to set fixed margins to get reliable overlap independent of the legend. At least, fixed top/bottom margins are enough if you set `size ratio -1`. Additionally, you can set the legend to a fixed position relative to the screen.
- I recommended to unset border, tics and labels for the second plot, otherwise these elements get a slight "bold" appearance if you plot them several times on top of each other (you will notice if you compare the numbers on Ethan's first and second plot)
- zooming is not possible with multiplot in interactive terminals, e.g. wxt, qt
- requires another multiplot if you want to *plot* single/multiple points from another file/datablock
- so far, I haven't found out how to freely control the color of the contour lines. But I'm sure there is a way.

```
### plot several contour plots and add a single point (multiplot)
reset session

f(x,y) = 2*x**2 - x + 2*y**2 - y - 2
g(x,y) = (x-1)**2 + y**2 - 1

set xlabel "x-label"
set xrange [-3:3]
set ylabel "y-label"
set yrange [-3:3]
set samples 100
set isosamples 100
set contour
unset surface
set view map

set size ratio -1
set multiplot

    xPos = 0.95
    set key at screen xPos,0.9 title "Main title" font ",12"
    set bmargin screen 0.15
    set tmargin screen 0.92
    set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
    splot f(x,y) w l

    set cntrparam levels discrete 0
    unset border
    unset tics
    unset xlabel
    unset ylabel
    set key at screen xPos,0.5 notitle
    splot g(x,y) w l
 
    set key at screen xPos,0.35 notitle
    plot '+' u (1):(1) every ::::0 w p pt 7 lc "red" ti "You are here"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Script (single plot):**

- zooming possible in interactive terminals, e.g. wxt, qt
- extra tables for contours
- a bit more effort with the legend (but auto positioning)
- easy customization of contour line color

For the single plot, the extraction of the contour level labels is a bit tricky and needs some explanations.
The contour data in the datablocks looks like this:

```
# Surface 0 of 1 surfaces

# Curve title: "f(x,y)"

# Contour 0, label:        5
-1 -1.15789  5 
-1.15789 -1  5 
-1.54386 -0.333333  5
...
-0.333333 -1.54386  5 
-1 -1.15789  5 


# Contour 1, label:        4
-0.333333 -1.38596  4
...
```

The data is separated by two empty lines. So, you can address the subblocks by using `index` (check `help index`).
So, now, after skipping the first 5 lines, you need to extract the contour label value from each the first line (header) of each (sub)block from the 5th column. For this, you need to tell gnuplot that `#` is *not* a comment character anymore (check `help datafile commentschars`).

Furthermore, the legend entry for the functions names are realized by keyentries (check `help keyentry`) with a fully transparent point according to the color scheme `0xaarrggbb` where alpha is `0xff´.

```
### plot several contour plots and add a single point (single plot)
reset session

f(x,y) = 2*x**2 - x + 2*y**2 - y - 2
g(x,y) = (x-1)**2 + y**2 - 1

set xlabel "x-label"
set xrange [-3:3]
set ylabel "y-label"
set yrange [-3:3]
set samples 100
set isosamples 100
set contour
unset surface
set table $ContourF
    set cntrparam levels incremental  0,1,5
    splot f(x,y)
set table $ContourG
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0
    splot g(x,y)
unset table

set size ratio -1
set key noautotitle left at graph 1.05,1 title "Main title" font ",12"
set datafile commentschar ''

plot keyentry w p lc rgb 0xff123456 ti "f(x,y)", \
     for [i=0:*] $ContourF u 1:2:3 skip 5 index i w l lc i ti columnhead(5), \
     keyentry w p lc rgb 0xff123456 ti "g(x,y)", \
     for [i=0:*] $ContourG u 1:2:3 skip 5 index i w l lc "blue" ti columnhead(5), \
     '+' u (1):(1) every ::::0 w p pt 7 lc "red" ti "You are here"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]